# Maven: Is there ever a reason to explicitly set a profile's activeByDefault to false?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I am in the midst of a semi-major refactor of an existing Maven project with a number of POMs. There are a number of POMs with profiles that have their `<activeByDefault>` set to `false`, like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>someProfile</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    ...
    <properties>...</properties>
</profile>
```

With no other activation criteria, these profiles simply must be activated explicity by using `-PsomeProfile`, right? Is there ever a time something that is declared as inactive by default would get activated, perhaps relative to a profile that is active by default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most used scenario. You declare a profile because you don't want this logic to be used (at least sometimes). And if you *do* want this, *then* you active the profile.

From top of my head - we use different repos for the deployment depending on the stage of the build (passed unit tests/passed system tests/released). The properties & passwords are located in the `settings.xml` and we change them with `-Pbuilds_verified`, `-Pbuilds_released`.

There are of course cases when you want profiles depending on the environment (e.g. OS), but in my experience those are relatively rare.

PS: though profiles are not active by default anyway, so you could skip the explicit deactivation.